# Paypal login with custom layout in android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating `PayPal` into my project and I want to login `PayPal` via my own custom layout in which I have define two `edittext` for `email address`, `password` and one `button` for make `api` call to login into `paypal`. I have seen sample application in which `PayPal` default dialog opens in which we can enter credential for login it but in my case I want to get login via through `own layout`. So please help me to get such functionality. I have also refer [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java).

Below is my MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "credentials from developer.paypal.com";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Example Merchant")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));


    private EditText etEmailAddress,etPasswowrd;
    private Button btnLogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etEmailAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmailAddress);
        etPasswowrd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPasswowrd);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Here I want to login into PayPal
            }
        });
    }
}
```